# Symfony with FOS User Bundle and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, symfony, csrf, fosuserbundle

I'm having problems with login site for FOS User Bundle using AngularJS. I have few questions that may help me resolve my problems.

**1. What exactly is csrf and what for do I need it?**

**2. Where do I implement POST arguments recived from AngularJS to FOS User Bundle to make user logged**

---

At this moment all I have is:

---

```
namespace Common\UserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class SecurityController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {

        $parameters = $this->transformAction();
        var_dump($parameters);
        return $parameters;

    }

public function transformAction()

    {
    $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
    $parametersAsArray = [];
    $content = $request->getContent();
    $parametersAsArray = json_decode($content, true);

    return $parametersAsArray;  
    }

}
```

And client-side:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('loginApp', [])
    .controller('LoginController', LoginController);

  LoginController.$inject = ['$http'];

  //////////

  function LoginController($http) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.submitLoginForm = submitLoginForm;

    ///// EVENTS
    function submitLoginForm() {
      var form = {
        login  : vm.login,
        passwd : vm.passwd
      };

      $http.post('user/login', form)
    }

  };

}())
```

What shall I do next?